# What is the purpose of "for (;;);" in some API response?

Tags: javascript

I've noticed that some API response add this code `for (;;);` at the very begining.

For example:

Instagram: https://www.instagram.com/coldplay/?__a=1

Response:

```json
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"error":1357004,"errorSummary":"\u5509\u5440\uff0c\u597d\u50cf\u6709\u6771\u897f\u51fa\u932f\u4e86","errorDescription":"\u8acb\u5617\u8a66\u95dc\u9589\u4e26\u91cd\u65b0\u958b\u555f\u4f60\u7684\u700f\u89bd\u5668\u8996\u7a97\u3002","payload":null,"hsrp":{"hblp":{"consistency":{"rev":1007698095}}},"lid":"7245339430614877794"}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Which API is returning that?

Comment: I did find an example of a for loop where 1st and 3rd parameters are omitted. `for (; i < len; )` not sure what would happen if 2nd parameter is omitted.

Comment: That response is JavaScript, not JSON. `for(;;);` is an infinite loop that will hang the browser if it's loaded as a script. I think they're trying to prevent people from fetching it as JSONP.

Comment: Old School way to prevent people from linking to your files and executing them.

Comment: @epascarello But there's nothing in there to execute, it's just a data object.